# chown: Operation not permitted for root on ext4 root-partition

Tags: linux, chown, ubuntu-16.04

After upgrading from Ubuntu v14.04 to v16.04 chown doesn't seem to work any longer on my server.
I checked following:

- filesystem is RW
- user exists
- folder is not immutable
- all commands executed as root

and for the heck i tried following (as root):

```
$ id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
$ apparmor_status
apparmor module is loaded.
0 profiles are loaded.
0 profiles are in enforce mode.
0 profiles are in complain mode.
0 processes have profiles defined.
0 processes are in enforce mode.
0 processes are in complain mode.
0 processes are unconfined but have a profile defined.
$ cd /
$ > test.txt
$ chmod 777 test.txt
$ lsattr test.txt 
-------------e-- test.txt
$ ls -l test.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun 27 19:01 test.txt
$ chown www-data test.txt
chown: changing ownership of 'test.txt': Operation not permitted
```

Anyone any suggestions?

Comment: As far as i know you cannot change the owner of a file to a user you have no access to. Or did you execute the chown as root?

Comment: Please check if you are root user. You can use id command to check the same.

Comment: yes, it was executed as root and I even checked apparmor if there were any odd enforcing profiles loaded. (plz see question update for more clarification)